# How to run delete query on Memsql/singlestore using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, singlestore

I am able to connect to singlestore and load the data into a dataframe using
`spark.read.format("memsql")` and also write to singlestore using `dataframe.write.format("memsql")`

But I need to run a delete query for ex: `Delete from tableA where id=1;` to delete a record in singlestore through my pyspark code

I am not able to find any documentation in the singlestore website.

Answer (score 1):

SingleStore’s pyspark connector allows python to use dataframes connected to SingleStore. All dataframes are immutable (unable to be changed) and WORM (write once, read many times). The technique to be used is to filter the dataframe by creating a second dataframe.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df2 = df.where(id = 1)
df2.show()
```

You can use a different connection method in python to delete the rows. The SingleStoreDB Python Connector will allow you to connect without a dataframe and then use standard SQL to delete the row.

```
import singlestoredb as s2
conn = s2.connect(host='localhost', port='3306', user='root', password='passkey', database='dbTest', results_type='tuple')

with conn:
    conn.autocommit(True)
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('DELETE FROM testID WHERE ID = 2')
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM testID')
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            print(row)
```

https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v8.0/en/developer-resources/connect-with-application-development-tools/connect-with-python/connect-using-the-singlestoredb-python-client.html#delete-operation-example-755699